# Translation of SNMP traps dosen't work in check_mk

Tags: snmp, mib, network-monitoring, snmp-trap, check-mk

I'm working on processing SNMP traps from CISCO devices by check_mk 1.2.8p20 version. The configuration is in progress and I've have already untranslated traps in Event Console.

Here (http://mathias-kettner.com/cms_ec.html) is simple instruction how to do it but it doesn't work. I followed instruction contained in 7.3 and 7.4 chapter and still nothing. I have around 2500 MIB files from tools.cisco dot com/ITDIT/MIBS/MainServlet

In directory /omd/sites/mySite/local/share/check_mk/compiled_mibs are all of my mibs complied by check_mk, but I had a problem with uploading:

> Failed to compile your module: no module "ADSL-LINE-MIB" in symbolTable at MIB ADSL-DMT-LINE-MIB

and

> You are missing the needed pysmi python module (cannot import name defaultMibPackageds).

I've solved it by clue founded in this page:
http://git.mathias-kettner.de/git/?p=check_mk.git;a=commitdiff;h=becad1bc22064ed7287aeec5b086e2d4edf6c010

A few days ago when I turned on SNMP trap translation first time (7.3, mathias-kettner dot com/cms_ec.html) it seemed to partialy work.

For instance:

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.0.1   SNMPv2-MIB::sysUpTime.0: 217843968 , SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB::snmpTrapAddress.0: 172.16.5.5 , SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB::snmpTrapCommunity.0: , SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapEnterprise.0: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9 , SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.2.9.3.1.1.2.1: 6, SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6.13.1.1.172.16.1.1.22.136.62.73.219.36158: 8, SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.2.6.1.1.5.172.16.1.1.22.136.62.73.219.36158: 408, SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.2.6.1.1.1.172.16.1.1.22.136.62.73.219.36158: 2565, SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.2.6.1.1.2.172.16.1.1.22.136.62.73.219.36158: 1456, SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.2.9.2.1.18.2: minera
```

but now traps are untranslated although appropriate MIBs are loaded and SNMP traps translation option is turned on:

```
1.3.6.1.4.1.9.0.1   1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0: 455413843, 1.3.6.1.6.3.18.1.3.0: ¬, 1.3.6.1.6.3.18.1.4.0: , 1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.3.0: 1.3.6.1.4.1.9, 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.2.9.3.1.1.1.1: 6, 1.3.6.1.2.1.6.13.1.1.172.16.1.1.22.80.229.253.212.35849: 1, 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.2.6.1.1.5.172.16.1.1.22.80.229.253.212.35849: 4246, 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.2.6.1.1.1.172.16.1.1.22.80.229.253.212.35849: 23, 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.2.6.1.1.2.172.16.1.1.22.80.229.253.212.35849: 388, 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.2.9.2.1.18.1:
```

Anybody have some clue for me?

PS. All changes in check_mk were saved and config was reloaded.

Comment: Is this a programming question? I'm not sure I see it. Please consider moving your question to ServerFault.com instead.

Comment: How can I move it there? I've already solve the problem and I can share my solution.

Comment: I've flagged the question as "off-topic" so hopefully a mod can migrate it. However you can also choose to just repost your question there and delete this one.